# How to print two attribute values from your Sub query table

Tags: sql, join, subquery, relational-database, aggregate-functions

Suppose I have two tables,

1. User
2. Post

Posts are made by Users (i.e. the Post Table will have **foreign key of user**)

Now my question is,

*Print the details of all the users who have more than 10 posts*

To solve this, I can type the following query and it would give me the desired result,

```
SELECT * from USER where user_id in (SELECT user_id from POST group by user_id having count(user_id) > 10)
```

The problem occurs when I also want to print the Count of the Posts along with the user details. Now obtaining the count of user is not possible from USER table. That can only be done from POST table. But, I can't get two values from my subquery, i.e. I can't do the following,

```
SELECT * from USER where user_id in (SELECT user_id, **count(user_id)** from POST group by user_id having count(user_id) > 10)
```

So, how do I resolve this issue? One solution I know is this, but this I think it would be a very naive way to resolve this and will make the query much more complex and also much more slow,

```
SELECT u.*, (SELECT po.count(user_id) from POST as po group by user_id having po.count(user_id) > 10) from USER u where u.user_id in (SELECT p.user_id from POST p group by user_id having p.count(user_id) > 10)
```

Is there any other way to solve this using subqueries?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok I am doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the aggregation to the `from` clause:

```
SELECT u.*, p.num_posts
FROM user u JOIN
     (SELECT p.user_id, COUNT(*) as num_posts
      FROM post p
      GROUP BY p.user_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 10
     ) p
     ON u.user_id = p.user_id;
```

You can do this with subqueries:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*,
             (select count(*) from post p where p.user_id = u.user_id) as num_posts
      from users u
     ) u
where num_posts > 10;
```

With an index on `post(user_id)`, this might actually have better performance than the version using `JOIN`/`GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer... Is it also possible to do it with subquery?

Answer (score 1):

You can try by joining the tables, Prefer to do a `JOIN` than using `SUBQUERY`

```
SELECT user.*, count( post.user_id ) as postcount
FROM user LEFT JOIN post ON users.user_id = post.user_id
GROUP BY post.user_id
HAVING postcount > 10 ;
```

Comment: Greatly appreciate the answer! ^_^ can you tell that whether it is possible to do the same with subquery as well? 
and why would you prefer Left Join in this case? Wouldn't it display ALL The users (where in fact, the problem requires only those users who have 10+ posts)

Comment: I have edited my answer to retrieve the users with post count greater than 10, The reason i preferred left join was because you'll get all users if there is no posts (based on my previous answer which is now not much relevant).`The retrieval time of the query using joins almost always will be faster than that of a subquery` so i would suggest to use join.